# Commit in PLSQL loop for update

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

I am using the below function in my java program to copy a column from temporary table to main table.

```
FUNCTION TEST(TBL_NAME VARCHAR2, TMP_TBL_NAME VARCHAR2, ID_COL VARCHAR2, REQ_COL VARCHAR2, BATCH_SIZE NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ' || TMP_TBL_NAME INTO TOTAL_RECORDS;
OFFSET := 0;
WHILE OFFSET < TOTAL_RECORDS
LOOP
  MAX_RESULTS := OFFSET + BATCH_SIZE;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || ID_COL || ', ' || REQ_COL || ' FROM ' || TMP_TBL_NAME || ' WHERE SEQ_NBR BETWEEN :OFFSET AND :MAX_RESULTS' BULK COLLECT INTO SEQ_IDS, REQ_COL_VALUESS USING OFFSET, MAX_RESULTS;
  FORALL IND IN SEQ_IDS.FIRST .. SEQ_IDS.LAST
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE ' || TBL_NAME || ' SET ' || REQ_COL || ' = :REQ_COL_VAL WHERE ' || ID_COL || ' = :ID_COL_VAL' USING REQ_COL_VALUESS(IND), SEQ_IDS(IND);
  OFFSET := MAX_RESULTS;
  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
RETURN 0;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE CUST_EXCEPTION; 
END;
```

Expected result is when I am running with a batch_size of 100000, for each commit 100000 records have to be updated as id_col I used above is primary key. After running the java program, in middle when I am checking for updates in main table I am able to see that records of batches 6469 or 80148 like that are being updated.

There are about 10 million records in temp table. If I remove the forall update statement I am iterating over the data in proper batch size.

Can any clarify me on why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

1) How many records do you have in your temporary tables?

2) Why you don't use sys_refcursor and bulk collect with limit ?

```
declare 
 v_cursor sys_refcursor; 
 res1 sys.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL; -- - predefined collection in oracle 
 res2 sys.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL;
 v_batch_size pls_integer := 50;
begin 
 open v_cursor for 'Select 1,2 from dual connect by level < 10000';
 loop
 fetch v_cursor bulk collect into res1,res2 limit v_batch_size;
 exit when res1.count =0;
    dbms_output.put_line(res1.count);
  -- forall ind in res1.first .. res1.last loop e.g 
  -- commit;
 end loop;
  close v_cursor;
end;
```

Comment: I tried with cursor also. Problem I am having is not with iteration but with update in forall. For all the records in temp table there is a record in main table. Still the number of records when I checked that are updated does not equal to multiples of my batch_size.

Comment: e.g BATCH_SIZE = 10
iteration 1 offset = 0, max_result = 10;
iteration 2 offset = 10, max_result = 20;
select seg from ( Select level seg from dual connect by level < 1000)  where seg between 0 and 10;
select seg from ( Select level seg from dual connect by level < 1000)  where seg between 10 and 20; 
Examine the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- first iteration offset= 0 , max_result = 10 
-- v_batch_size = 10
-- offset := 0 
--  MAX_RESULTS := 10 
select seg from ( Select level seg from dual connect by level < 1000)  where seg between 0 and 10;
-- secound iteration 
-- v_batch_size = 10
-- offset := 10 
--  MAX_RESULTS := 20 
select seg from ( Select level seg from dual connect by level < 1000) where seg between 10 and 20;
```